# Grails remote field - paramName and params together

Tags: grails

I noticed something when I was attempting this today:

```
<g:remoteField action="getReportsToResults" update="reportsToResultsDiv" paramName="search" name="reportsToResults" value="" />
```

I have this section of code where my remoteField is updating a div that contains a selection box. It works, but I want to limit the results passed to the div based on a domain instance attribute value (company ID). I have the instance variable (contactInstance.company).

When I try to add the params to that code, the value of search goes to '+this.value+', instead of the actual value of the text field. How does that happen and how do I pass both the field value and another parameter?

```
<g:remoteField action="getReportsToResults" update="reportsToResultsDiv" paramName="search" params="[company:contactInstance.company]" name="reportsToResults" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error your are getting is because remoteFeild does not accept params as its parameters and when you use the keyword params it confuses the code (take a look at remotefield sourcecode).  If you need to pass a parameter I would suggest to put them in Id and pass it to your controller.

for example :

```
  <g:remoteField action="getReportsToResults" update="reportsToResultsDiv" paramName="search" params="[company:contactInstance.company]" name="reportsToResults" value="" id = "123"/>
```

RemoteField params are:

name (required) - the name of the field

value (optional) - The initial value of the field

paramName (optional) - The name of the parameter send to the server

action (optional) - the name of the action to use in the link, if not specified the default action will be linked

controller (optional) - the name of the controller to use in the link, if not specified the current controller will be linked

id (optional) - The id to use in the link

update (optional) - Either a map containing the elements to update for 'success' or 'failure' states, or a string with the element to update in which cause failure events would be ignored

before (optional) - The javascript function to call before the remote function call

after (optional) - The javascript function to call after the remote function call

asynchronous (optional) - Whether to do the call asynchronously or not (defaults to true)

method (optional) - The method to use the execute the call (defaults to "post")

source code from 1.3.7

```
def remoteField = { attrs, body ->
    def paramName = attrs.paramName ? attrs.remove('paramName') : 'value'
    def value = attrs.remove('value')
    if (!value) value = ''
    out << "<input type=\"text\" name=\"${attrs.remove('name')}\" value=\"${value}\" onkeyup=\""

    if (attrs.params) {
        if (attrs.params instanceof Map) {
            attrs.params[paramName] = new JavascriptValue('this.value')
        }
        else {
            attrs.params += "+'${paramName}='+this.value"
        }
    }
    else {
        attrs.params = "'${paramName}='+this.value"
    }
    out << remoteFunction(attrs)
    attrs.remove('params')
    out << "\""
    attrs.remove('url')
    attrs.each { k,v->
        out << " $k=\"$v\""
    }
    out <<" />"
}
```

Comment: Bizzare, but I got around the problem by using the ID field. Thanks!